# Redirect channel to another speaker

Tags: surround-sound, creative

I'm not sure about the title but don't know how to say it in a clearer way.

My Soundcard is a Creative X-Fi and I'm using the Creative console starter.

Now I'd like to use my speakers not only for my normal screens but also when using a beamer.
Due to my room's geometry, the only place for the beamer's projection is a wall which is right to my normal screens (so the projection would be between the front right and the rear right speaker).

Now I'm thinking about redirecting the channels to the correct speakers somehow. As far as I remember, in previous version of creative console starter there was an option to do this (e.g. redirect front left to rear right output channel).

Does anyone know how to do this with software? Of course I could install a cable switch, but if there's a way without I'd prefer this :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) allows you to do this.

You can configure virtual cables with it and redirect audio in both ways..